# No RTE after Typo3 update

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I updated Typo3 from 6.x to 8.x and now i don't have the the RTE anymore in the "Text & Media".
I already added "RTE.default.preset = full" to the Typoscript but without success.
Can somone maybe help me maybe?

Comment: rte_ckeditor extension is active? Do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: I'm an Idiot. Didn't knew it is an externsion. Thank you!

Comment: I'll add a quick answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 8.7.x, the Rich Text Editor functionality is provided by the system extension EXT:rte_ckeditor (previously, by EXT:rtehtmlarea instead) so in case of an update from an old version to 8.7.x, check in Extension Manager if the extension is currently activated.

Other possible sources of same problem (editor not loaded) can be

- non-existent .yaml configuration file (or can't be loaded)
- errors inside the .yaml configuration file, so that the configuration is broken
- other javascript errors that prevent the editor to be loaded (I'd flush the backend cache and the browser cache before investigating these)